# Http get request giving forbidden response in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

HTTP "POST" data with login credentials to the BASEn server using API URL, in response it is giving a status 200, OK.

```
 var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mode", "login"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", logintxtbx.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", passtxtbx.Text)

                };

            httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://xx-yyy.com/auth", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));                                                                      var strin = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageBox.Show("login Success");
            GetFullResponse(httpClient);
    }
```

After validating my credentials, the server will create a session to me if i try to do "GET" HTTP by using another urls, it should gives my required data but this thing was not happening, every time iam getting "403" forbidden response.
This is the code using for "GET" data.

```
  var uri = new Uri("https://xx-yyy.com/_ua/web/web/v1/xyz/?xyx=1431369000000&end=1431436740000&_=1431436741550");
            var Response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            var statusCode = Response.StatusCode;
            Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
            var ResponseText = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

i don't know whats wrong, i was doing.
Can any one suggest me how can i do this to be happen.

Comment: What you are trying to do will not work. Usually when you login to a website, it sets a cookie in your browser so that it can authenticate further requests coming from the same browser for that user. In your case it has no way to authenticate the further requests and so you are getting FORBIDDEN response. If it is your own website you might want to issue an authentication token in response of a login and store the token in the phone for authentication future requests.

Comment: Hi, Akshay, Thanks for the response, can you please provide me a sample code to achieve this.

Comment: Are you the owner of the site you are trying to login to?

Comment: No, it is not our server but we had a credentials to access it and we have a web application which was using the same server where cookies take handling of creating a session for the user and able access data with GET or POST https urls if we open in new tab of same browser.Here web browser cookies is taking care of authenticating user sessions for next url sending to get data. same way i want achieve in windows phone. please,suggest me how can i do this

Comment: `var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var cookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);`

store cookies using cookieContainer and use them to authenticate the future calls using the same way as on web.

Answer (score 0):

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
var cookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

store cookies using cookieContainer and use them to authenticate the future calls using the same way as on web.

Store the cookies to the phone using IsolatedStorageSettings

Reference for more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd920298%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)